# AUTOSAR CanTpAddress and ISO 15765 CAN N_PDU relation

Tags: autosar

CanTpAddress in AUTOSAR is indirectly mapped to which field of ISO 15765 Specification for Functional Addressing purpose?
Shown below some snippets for reference
Some meaningful implementation related information related to CanTpAddress field will help me a lot. I am assuming it is applicable only for Functional Diagnostic Request type purpose.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CanTpAddress is for both FUNCTIONAL and PHYSICAL  addressing.

They correlate to ISO-15765

- `N_SA` SourceAddress  -> `CanTpAddress.tpAddress` of `CanTpNode` referenced by `CanTpConnection.transmitter`
- `N_TA` TargetAddress  -> `CanTpAddress.tpAddress` of `CanTpNode` referenced by `CanTpConnection.receivers` of physical or directly in `CanTpConnection.multicast` for functional
- `N_AE` AddressExtension (Extended/Mied Addressing) -> `CanTpAddress.tpAddressExtensionValue`
- `N_TAtype` functional req vs physical req/res `CanTpConnection.taType`

Comment: But CanTpConnection Multiplicity is 0 or 1. Then for a single CanTpConnection entity, it should be at least 2 always as Multiplicity because 1 transmitter and 1 receiver for PHYSICAL Address use case. That is where confusion.

Comment: A CanTpConnection has a transmitter CanTpNode, a list of receiver CanTpNodes, and for functional it has 1 multicast CanTpAddress. For transmitter and receiver, the CanTpNodes have a tpAddress element for CanTpAddress.